# Function is not defined when call Js function in PHP Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project. In my blade view, I have a Javascript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function autoFill (dropDown, emptyDropDown) {
            $("#" + dropDown ).change(function() { 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bcnss",

                    success: function(response){

                        var dataLength = response.length;

                        $("#" + emptyDropDown).empty();

                        $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
                        for( var i = 0; i< dataLength; i++){
                            var id = response[i].id;
                            var name = response[i].name;
                            $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value='"+id+"'>" + name + " </option>");
                        }                 
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Then, I call this function in the body tag and pass two php parameters to it:

```
<?php echo "<script> autoFill('$dropDown', '$emptyDropDown'); </script>"; ?>
```

But when I run this, I got a error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: autoFill is not defined".

Here is my full code in blade view if you want:

```html
<body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Activiti Form
                </div>

            @if(isset($formDataResult) && isset($dropdownValue))

                <div class="links">
                    <form action="{{ url('handle-form') }}" method="POST">
                            <!--Loop form data and call components to render form-->
                            @foreach($formDataResult as $formDataValue)
                                <div class="links">   
                                        
                                    @if($formDataValue['type'] == 'select')

                                        @if(array_key_exists('description',$formDataValue))

                                            <?php
                                                $dropDown = $formDataValue['name']
                                            ?>
                                        
                                            @component('components/InputSelect',[
                                                'name' =>   $formDataValue['label'],
                                                'id' => $formDataValue['name'],
                                                'enumData' => $dropdownValue
                                            ])
                                            @endcomponent

                                        @else

                                            <?php
                                                $emptyDropDown = $formDataValue['name'];
                                            ?>

                                            @component('components/EmptyInputSelect',[
                                                'name' =>   $formDataValue['label'],
                                                'id' => $formDataValue['name']
                                            ])
                                            @endcomponent

                                        @endif

                                    @elseif($formDataValue['type'] == 'text')

                                        @component('components/InputText',[
                                            'name' => $formDataValue['label'],
                                            'id' => $formDataValue['name'],
                                            'type'=>$formDataValue['type']
                                        ])
                                        @endcomponent

                                    @endif
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                            <?php echo "<script> autoFill('$dropDown', '$emptyDropDown'); </script>"; ?>

                            <!--Hidden input to store task id-->
                            @component('components/HiddenInput',[
                                    'id' => $taskId
                                ])
                            @endcomponent  
                             
                        <div>
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
                            <button type="submit">Complete Task</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!--If don't have form data, show error alert-->
                @else
                    <div class="alert">
                        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
                        <strong>Notice!</strong> There are no tasks at this moment! 
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function autoFill (dropDown, emptyDropDown) {
            $("#" + dropDown ).change(function() { 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bcnss",
                                              
                    success: function(response){
                        
                        var dataLength = response.length;
                        
                        $("#" + emptyDropDown).empty();
                    
                        $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
                        for( var i = 0; i< dataLength; i++){
                            var id = response[i].id;
                            var name = response[i].name;
                            $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value='"+id+"'>" + name + " </option>");
                        }                 
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        
    </script>
```

How I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the definition come before the calling? Is there any error in the definition that might prevent it from getting defined?

Comment: you can't get js value to PHP

Comment: I'm quite new to Js so I really don't know what's it problem?

Comment: I passed PHP var to my Js function. I don't get any Js value to PHP.

Comment: now check my answer. I give an example of how to read PHP variable values in JS.

Comment: try this for call function `<script type="text/javascript">autoFill({{$dropDown}} , {{$emptyDropDown}});</script>`

Comment: thanks for your help! I fixed this by moving the script tag to top before I call the function and it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the function before you define it. Put the `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` defining the function *before* your `<script> autoFill('$dropDown', '$emptyDropDown'); </script>` which tries to call it.

Comment: I fixed to this:<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'> autoFill('$dropDown', '$emptyDropDown'); </script>"; ?> . But it still got that error.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood. Your `function autoFill(...) ...` which *defines* the function is somewhere at the bottom of your page. The code that tries to *call* that function is somewhere before. *That's* the problem!

Answer (score -1):

You can read js value to using PHP. But you can print js value to HTML screen.

You have a `<span>` or `<div>` tag with `class` or `id` attribute then you can place your value inside that.

Here is your js functionality

```
<script>

    // whatever value you need in your js from PHP. you need to below code.

    let dropdown = <?php echo $dropDown; ?>
    let emptyDropdown = <?php echo $emptyDropDown; ?>


    // now pass your js variables here.
    function autoFill (dropDown, emptyDropDown) {
        $("#" + dropDown ).change(function() { 

            let $this = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bcnss",

                success: function(response){

                    var dataLength = response.length;

                    $("#" + emptyDropDown).empty();

                    $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
                    for( var i = 0; i< dataLength; i++){
                        var id = response[i].id;
                        var name = response[i].name;
                        $("#" + emptyDropDown).append("<option value='"+id+"'>" + name + " </option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What difference does it make, if you echo the PHP values to separate JS variables instead of the function argument values? Not my down vote, though.

Comment: you can't directly access PHP variables in JS. before use PHP variables to JS., you need to firstly print PHP variable value and store that to JS variable. Then you can access that PHP variable value to your JS code.

Comment: They're not directly accessing PHP variables in JS, they're echoing the values to the page, exactly in the same way as you're doing it in your example.